# SQS CloudWatch Log group

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I saw CloudWatch metrics logged for my SQS queue and operations.

However I want to view the details and events/ data of the sent messages. I have cloudwatch log group permissions for my SQS queue, but I still don't see the logging in Cloud Watch log groups.

I read from the documentation that logging is done with CloudTrail

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-logging-using-cloudtrail.html

but can't we log through Cloudwatch log group too? Noticed that for SQS Cloudwatch is only applicable for the monitoring of metrics

Comment: Did you follow the instructions from your link to setup the logging? Sadly your question is not clear and lacks details.

Comment: i thought i have shared quite clearly that i want cloud watch logs instead of cloudtrail. the link indicated cloudtrail events logging. not cloudwatch logs as log groups. i searched but nothing related to cloud watch logging for sqs

Comment: cloudtrail can be set to push logs to CW logs. Without that, its not possible to do what you want.

Comment: @Marcin thanks i am aware that CloudTrail can be pushed to CW logs. Just that my question was around the integration for CW directly for SQS without having to configure to push from cloudtrail (similar to what usually lambda / API Gateway can do to get in CW log group directly). thanks for clarifying.

Comment: There is no direct integration between sqs and cw logs.